# .First.lib idiom in R packages

Tags: r, package

I see the following idiom in the .First.lib function in a lot of R packages:

```
fullName <- paste("package", pkgname, sep=":")
myEnv <- as.environment(match(fullName, search()))
barepackage <- sub("([^-]+)_.*", "\\1", pkgname)
dbbase <- file.path(libname, pkgname, "R", barepackage)
rm(.First.lib, envir = myEnv)
lazyLoad(dbbase, myEnv)
if(exists(".First.lib", envir = myEnv, inherits = FALSE)) {
    f <- get(".First.lib", envir = myEnv, inherits = FALSE)
    if(is.function(f))
        f(libname, pkgname)
    else
        stop(gettextf("package '%s' has a non-function '.First.lib'",
                      pkgname),
             domain = NA)
}
```

I understand that the .First.lib function is run when a package is loaded.

I understand that the code above defines an environment for the package and sets up a path, but I don't understand why it's looking for a .First.lib function after it explicitly deletes the .First.lib function. What makes the above idiom so common? Is it a "best practice" to include this in an R package?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That kind of idiom is antique. Packages should have namespaces and use .onLoad, .onUnload and .onAttach. For example:

```
.onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname){
     # do whatever needs to be done when the package is loaded
     # some people use it to bombard users with 
     # messages using 
     packageStartupMessage( "my package is so cool" )
     packageStartupMessage( "so I will print these lines each time you load it")
}
```

The whold business with the calling the lazyLoad function is best avoided by just adding this to the DESCRIPTION file:

```
LazyLoad: true
```

Answer (score 3):

You ask why it is looking for `.First.Lib` when the script deleted it earlier. `lazyLoad` loads a database of R objects, which in the code above is loaded into the environment `myEnv`. It is not inconceivable that the set of objects loaded into that environment contains a `.First.Lib` and it is this that the code is looking for. Indeed, I guess the intention was to *only* run the `.First.Lib` that was stored in the object database loaded.

Another common idiom in packages without a NAMESPACE, is this (from the vegan package):

```
.First.lib <- function(lib, pkg)  {
    library.dynam("vegan", pkg, lib)
    packageStartupMessage("This is vegan ",
                          utils::packageDescription("vegan", field="Version"),
                          appendLF = TRUE)
}
```

This loads the compiled code ready for use and prints a simple start-up message with the package name and version number. This is similar in spirit to the `.onLoad` of @Romain's answer, but without the NAMESPACE.

Comment: It is very easy to use a NAMESPACE and it is useful. And here it gives you useDynLib to load the compiled code

Comment: @Romain: Thanks, yes. I am in the process of adding a NAMESPACE to the two packages I authored. The last time I spoke with the lead developer of vegan, he was dead set against adding one to the package. Whilst NAMESPACE files are not required for packages to pass R CMD check, I thought it worth documenting a much simpler `.First.lib` than the one @JD Long showed in his Q.